# Textviews in tablerow - alignment going weird after rotation (and one textview before as well)

Tags: android, textview, android-tablelayout

I'm making an app that lets you use a Nintendo 3DS as a game controller for android. I'm trying to build a UI for setting the keymap.

I'm using a tablelayout, with two table rows. The first contains 3 textviews to indicate which column belongs to which device, and the second contains a listview, with the button labels on it.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kRrJO.png)

As you can see, in the screenshot, in the top tablerow, the left and right textviews are centered perfectly, but the arrow in the middle is not. What makes this extra puzzling, is that the center textview xml tag is almost identical to the left and right's tags. (code below).

Now, the second problem. When I rotate my screen landscape, the alignment is the same as before. But after switching back to portrait, [the alignment gets even worse:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HweNL.png)

Here is my tablelayout xml:

```
<TableLayout
    android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1">

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#EEEEEE"
        android:paddingBottom="1dp"
        android:paddingTop="1dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_header_left_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="3DS"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_header_arrow"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="->"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:typeface="monospace" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_header_right_textview"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Android"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItem"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="normal" />

    </TableRow>

    <TableRow
        android:id="@+id/settings_keymap_list_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/keymap_list"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="100"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="217dp" />
    </TableRow>

</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it - I had to set the textview heights to `wrap_content` and make sure the fonts were all the same size.